# Check if specific characters are in a string

Tags: python, string, counting

I need to find and count how many characters can be found in a string. I have divided the characters into chars1[a:m] and chars2[n:z], and have two counters.

The output should be 0/14, but it is 0/1 instead. I think it only checks to see if one and only one item is contained and then exits out the loop. Is that the case?

Here is the code.

```
string_1 = "aaabbbbhaijjjm"

def error_printer(s):
    chars1 = "abcdefghijklm"
    chars2 = "nopqrstuvwxyz"
    counter1 = 0
    counter2 = 0

    if ((c in s) for c in chars1):
        counter1 += 1
    elif ((c in s) for c in chars2):
        counter2 += 1
    print(str(counter2) + "/" + str(counter1))

error_printer(string_1)
```

Comment: `(c in s) for c in chars1` is a generator, which happens to evaluate to true, so `counter1 += 1` is always executed. But it’s only always executed once since that’s an *if statement*, and not a loop.

Comment: You should probably stay away from generator expressions ("z for x in y") until you understand loops a little better.

Comment: Is the answer meant to `0 / 14` or `0 / 6`. You are only iterating over `charsX` and counting those items.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Number of characters in `chars1`/`chars2` that occur in `s`

That makes sense since you **increment with an `if` condition**. Since the `if` is *not* in a loop, you can increment it once.

Now we can *unfold* the generator **into a `for` loop**. This will solve one part of the problem and **generate `0/6`**:

```
for c in chars1:
    if c in s:
        counter1 += 1
for c in chars2:
    if c in s:
        counter2 += 1
```

Nevertheless, this still will not be terribly efficient: it requires *O(n)* worst case to check if a character is in a string. You can construct a `set` first with the characters in the string, and then perform lookups (which are usually *O(1)* on average case:

```
def error_printer(s):
    sset = set(s)
    chars1 = "abcdefghijklm"
    chars2 = "nopqrstuvwxyz"
    counter1 = 0
    counter2 = 0
    for c in chars1:
        if c in sset:
            counter1 += 1
    for c in chars2:
        if c in sset:
            counter2 += 1
    print(str(counter2) + "/" + str(counter1))
```

Now we have improved the efficiency, but it is still not very elegantly: it takes a lot of code, and furthermore one has to inspect the code in order to know what it does. We can use a `sum(..)` construct to calculate the number of elements that satisfy a certain constraint like:

```
def error_printer(s):
    sset = set(s)
    chars1 = "abcdefghijklm"
    chars2 = "nopqrstuvwxyz"
    counter1 = sum(c in sset for c in chars1)
    counter2 = sum(c in sset for c in chars2)
    print(str(counter2) + "/" + str(counter1))
```

This produces `0/6` since there are six characters in the `[A-M]` range that occur in `s` and 0 in the `[N-Z]` range that occur in `s`.

## Number of characters in `s` that occur in `char1`/`char2`

Based on the body of the question however, you want to **count the number of characters in `s` that occur in the two different ranges**.

An other related problem is counting the number of characters that occur in `char1`/`char2`. In that case we simply have to **swap the loops**:

```
def error_printer(s):
    chars1 = set("abcdefghijklm")
    chars2 = set("nopqrstuvwxyz")
    counter1 = sum(c in chars1 for c in s)
    counter2 = sum(c in chars2 for c in s)
    print(str(counter2) + "/" + str(counter1))
```

This produces `0/14` since there are 14 characters in `s` that occur in the `[A-M]` range (if `'a'` occurs twice in `s`, then we count it twice), and none of the characters in `s` occur in the `[N-Z]` range.

### Using range checks

Since we are working with **ranges**, we can use comparisons instead of element checks, and make it run with two comparison checks, like:

```
def error_printer(s):
    counter1 = sum('a' <= c <= 'm' for c in s)
    counter2 = sum('n' <= c <= 'z' for c in s)
    print(str(counter2) + "/" + str(counter1))
```

Answer (score 6):

Try to increment using an if condition, with a single loop over s.

```
for c in s:
    if c in char1:
        counter1 += 1
    if c in char2:
        counter2 += 1
```

Comment: I would also suggest converting `char1` and `char2` to `set`s, as to squeeze a bit of performance here.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to the for loops:

```
string_1 = "aaabbbbhaijjjm"

def error_printer(s):
    chars1 = "abcdefghijklm"
    chars2 = "nopqrstuvwxyz"

    counter1 = sum(s.count(c) for c in chars1)
    counter2 = sum(s.count(c) for c in chars2)

    print(str(counter2) + "/" + str(counter1))

error_printer(string_1)
```

Where you count how many times `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"`... show in the string input, then you sum it up.

It's still inefficient, but leverages the `string.count` and `sum` functions, making it a bit easier to read and understand what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

A single for loop over `s` for both counters:

```
string_1 = "aaabbbbhaijjjm"

def error_printer(s):
    chars1 = "abcdefghijklm"
    chars2 = "nopqrstuvwxyz"
    counter1 = 0
    counter2 = 0
    for c in s:
        if c in chars1:
            counter1 += 1
        if c in chars2:
            counter2 += 1
    print(str(counter2) + "/" + str(counter1))

error_printer(string_1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html) combined with `sum`:

```
from collections import Counter

def error_printer(s):
    cnts = Counter(s)
    chars1 = "abcdefghijklm"
    chars2 = "nopqrstuvwxyz"
    print(sum(cnts[c] for c in chars2), '/', sum(cnts[c] for c in chars1))

>>> error_printer("aaabbbbhaijjjm")
0 / 14
```

Comment: `cnts[<anykey>]` already returns `0` if it doesn't exist - doesn't it? E.g. `sum(cnts[c] for c in chars2)`

Answer (score 1):

As was already suggested, for loops are the way to go.  You used a generator expression as a boolean for the if statement, which will only ever run once.  The first expression was evaluated `True`, but that won’t make it run the enclosed code more than once.  Because the first `if` did run, however, the `elif` never even evaluated its conditional.  This is why you want for loops, but you shouldn't loop over char1 and char2, you want to loop over s:

```
for c in s:
    if c in char1:
        counter1 += 1
    if c in char2:
        counter2 += 1
print(str(counter2) + "/" + str(counter1))
```

This points us towards a few even slicker ways to do this, first by using the `c in charX` as the iterators:

```
for c in s:
    counter1 += c in char1
    counter2 += c in char2
```

Now this is getting to be a little bit less clear, but we can make it even cleaner by adding a second for loop:

```
char = [‘abcdefghijklm’,’nopqrstuvwxyz’]
counter = [0,0]
for c in s:
    for i in [0,1]:
        counter[i] += c in char[i]
```

This is probably pushing it a little bit too far, but I hope it helps you see how you can rearrange these things in python!

(edit based on comments below)

Comment: No, even worse: the generator never ran and never actually looped over any of the items. OP’s if condition just checked the truthiness value of the (non-executed) generator object. And that happens to be true.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Nvm, got confused with what everybody is referring to with “first expression”.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Yes that’s what I meant, sorry for not being more explicit.  Was my first post!

Comment: @StefanPochmann Oh yeah you’re right about the order. Sorry, I got mixed up because the print comes in reverse order. I’ll edit my response.  I still think the second expression was evaluated, but since `(c in s) for c in chars2` is false for each one, there was nothing to trigger the if.  I believe it’s an implicit “or” logic on the entire generated expression, though I haven’t tested that.

Comment: @ChrisMcElroy No, the second expression wasn't evaluated. At all. The `elif` only gets checked when the `if` failed. Which it didn't. And like poke said, neither generator ever even ran. A generator is true. Period. It doesn't matter what's "in" the generator. That's never checked.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Oh, right, forgot about the elif.  I had noticed that earlier, then forgot about it.  Thanks for straightening me out! (I’ll edit again too, for anybody else looking)